# using frame shadow effect display in case of IOS but not in case of UWP project in xamarin

Tags: android, ios, asp.net, windows, uwp

```
<Frame>  
       <Label Text="Hello Forms."></Label> 
</Frame>
```

I have used frame to display shadow but it not displaying in cross platform in case of U W P project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is already an issue people created in Github about this problem: [No shadows for UWP Frames?](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/7839)

A reply there said:

> Hm although the border [update is
>   triggered](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP/FrameRenderer.cs#L49)
>   by the HasShadow property, it doesn't seem to apply any shadow. Looks
>   like this never was implemented.

Xamarin team has noticed this issue and will work on it in future.

Also, there is a sample project that [use the DropDhadowPanel](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/340725/#Comment_340725) in UWP to get a shadow effect on a control., you can have a look at that thread and try it.

Code of custom renderer in UWP:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ShadowLabel), typeof(ShadowLabelRenderer))]
namespace EffectsDemo.UWP
{
    class ShadowLabelRenderer : ViewRenderer<ShadowLabel, DropShadowPanel>
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ShadowLabel> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control == null)
            {
                // Instantiate the native control and assign it to the Control property with
                // the SetNativeControl method
                var effect = (ShadowEffect)Element.Effects.FirstOrDefault(x => x is ShadowEffect);

                DropShadowPanel dsPanel = new DropShadowPanel();
                dsPanel.Content = new TextBlock() { Text = Element.Text };

                dsPanel.BlurRadius = effect.Radius;
                Windows.UI.Color color = Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(
                    Convert.ToByte(effect.Color.A * 255),
                    Convert.ToByte(effect.Color.R * 255),
                    Convert.ToByte(effect.Color.G * 255),
                    Convert.ToByte(effect.Color.B * 255));
                dsPanel.Color = color;
                dsPanel.OffsetX = effect.DistanceX;
                dsPanel.OffsetY = effect.DistanceY;

                SetNativeControl(dsPanel);
            }

            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {
                // Unsubscribe from event handlers and cleanup any resources
            }

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                // Configure the control and subscribe to event handlers
            }
        }
    }
}
```